# Get selected item in DropDownList ASP.NET MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, razor, selecteditem, html.dropdownlistfor

I know there are multiple threads on how to get the selected value of a DropDownList. However I can't find the right way to get this value from a partial view in my controller.

This is my partial view:

```
@model List<aptest.Models.answer>

@Html.DropDownList("dropdownlist", new SelectList(Model, "text", "text"))
<button type="submit">next</button>
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

In order to get dropdown value, wrap your select list in a form tag. Use models and `DropDownListFor` helper

### Razor View

```
@model MyModel

@using (Html.BeginForm("MyController", "MyAction", FormMethod.Post)
{
   @Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.Gender, MyModel.GetGenderValues())
   <input type="submit" value="Send" />
}
```

### Controller and other classes

```
public class MyController : Controller 
{
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult MyAction(MyModel model)
    {
        // Do something

        return View();
    }
}

public class MyModel
{
    public Gender Gender { get; set; }

    public static List<SelectListItem> GetGenderValues()
    {
        return new List<SelectListItem> 
        {
            new SelectListItem { Text = "Male", Value = "Male" };
            new SelectListItem { Text = "Female", Value = "Female" };
        };
    }
}

public enum Gender 
{
    Male, Female
}
```

And if you use partial view, simply pass your model in it:

```
@Html.Partial("MyPartialView", Model)
```

Comment: he wants to get value from partial view not normal view!!

Comment: @Neel it doesn't matters.

Comment: what do u mean by doesn't matter?

Comment: @Neel After the partial view has rendered it doesn't matter whether the dropdown was inside a partial view.So long it is rendered under a form tag its value is posted to the server and can be accessed in FormCollection or Request object.

Comment: Thank you very much, it's working! damn i have no idea how i could struggle so badly..

Comment: @AndreiMikhalevich This helps me bind to the list and POST back the value, but it does not choose the correct selected value.  How do you specify the selected value?

Comment: Ok, I found it.  I just added the selected value to the SelectList.  `@Html.DropDownList("dropdownlist", new SelectList(Model, "text", "text", Model.SelectedValue))`

Comment: @Andrei M -Thanks a lot!, for this i can used like this,                                                <select name="Gender" id="Gender">                
                <option name="Male" value="Male">Male</option>
                <option name="Female" value="Female">Female</option>                                                                           
            </select>  we can avoid list method.

Answer (score 2):

```
ViewData["list"] = myList.ToList();
```

**Razor**

```
@Html.DropDownList("ddl", new SelectList((System.Collections.IEnumerable)ViewData["list"], "Id", "Name"))
```

**Controller**

```
public ActionResult ActionName(String ddl)
{

  // now ddl has your dropdownlist's selected value i.e Id

}
```